# Обновление state происходит только после двух нажатий на кнопку

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

помогите пожалуйста с проблемой. Компонент получает контакты с сервера и диспатчит их в contactsReducer. При нажатии кнопки создается новый контакт который отправляется на сервер, далее делается запрос на сервер для получения обновленного списка контактов. Но обновление происходит после двух нажатий на кнопку, таким образом мы получаем два новых контакта, а рендерится только один, если нажать третий раз на кнопку, то появляется второй и т.д.

<----- компонент ----->

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {actionUpdateContactReducer} from '../redux/actions/actions'
class Test extends React.Component{


    componentDidMount() {
      this._updateContactField()
      }

      _createUser(){
          const user = {
              "name": "новый контакт" 
          }
          fetch('http://localhost:3000/contacts', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(user),
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => console.log(json))
          this._updateContactField()
      }

    _updateContactField(){
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/db")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.props._dispatchUpdade(result.contacts)
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
    }

    render(){
      console.log(this.state)
      return(
          <div className="mainContent">
             {this.props.contacts.map((contact, index)=>{
                 return(
                     <div key={index}>{contact.name}</div>
                 )
             })}
             <button onClick={this._createUser.bind(this)}>Добавить контакт</button>
          </div>
      )
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    contacts: state.contactsReducer.contacts
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return{
    _dispatchUpdade: contacts => dispatch(actionUpdateContactReducer(contacts))
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Test)
```

<----- contactsReducer.js ----->

```
import { _UPDATECONTACTSREDUCER } from '../actions/actionsTypes'
const initialState = {
    contacts: [],
}
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case _UPDATECONTACTSREDUCER:
            return {
                contacts: action.payload,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Перенеси в  _createUser() в последний then this._updateContactField()
.then(json => {console.log(json), this._updateContactField()})

Comment: @Lukas спасибо, помогло:)

Comment: Не за что :))))